Ordenamiento por montículo
estoy desarrollando un programa para el siguiente problema:
Descripción
Eres cuentahabiente del banco más popular de la región y por lo general la cola del banco es extremadamente larga. Además, cada cuentahabiente tiene una prioridad entera P y la política es que los clientes con prioridad más alta sean atendidos primero (aunque hayan llegado a la cola después), lo que puede ocasionar que algunos cuentahabientes con prioridad baja no sean atendidos.
Para solucionar esto y volver menos monótona la espera en la cola, el banco ha decidido realizar sorteos para que algunos clientes avancen más rápido. Durante el sorteo se extrae una letra y un entero I de la tómbola: a los clientes que estén formados en ese momento y cuyos nombres inicien con esa letra se les sumarán I puntos a su prioridad. En caso de que dos cuentahabientes tengan la misma prioridad, se atenderá al que haya llegado primero. Los eventos que suceden en la cola se representan de la siguiente forma:

C N P: llega un cuentahabiente de nombre N con prioridad inicial P.
S L I: se realizó un sorteo y se extrajo la letra L y el entero I.
A: se atendió al cuentahabiente de mayor prioridad de la cola.

Escribe un programa que determine el nombre del cliente que fue atendido en cada evento de atención.
Entrada
Un entero E seguido de E eventos. Puedes suponer 1 ≤ E ≤ 50000, que no se atenderá a nadie mientras la cola esté vacía, que la prioridad de los cuentahabientes está en el intervalo de -1 000 000 a 1 000 000 y que tanto los nombres como las letras del sorteo consisten de letras mayúsculas.
Salida
Los nombres de los cuentahabientes atendidos en el orden en el que se atendieron.
Para poder resolver este problema, utilicé una estructura de datos como un montículo (heap) para mantener a los cuentahabientes en orden de prioridad, y así poder atender al que tiene la prioridad más alta en cada evento de atención.
El problema que persiste es que me marcan mi código como Tiempo Límite Excedido (TLE).
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?
Mi código es el siguiente:
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Estructura para representar a un cuentahabiente
struct Cuentahabiente {
    string nombre;
    int prioridad;
    int ordenDeLlegada; // Usado para desempatar en caso de igual prioridad
    // Constructor
    Cuentahabiente(string nombre, int prioridad, int ordenDeLlegada) : nombre(nombre), prioridad(prioridad), ordenDeLlegada(ordenDeLlegada) {}
    // Sobrecarga del operador < para comparar cuentahabientes por prioridad y orden de llegada
    bool operator<(const Cuentahabiente& otro) const {
        if (prioridad != otro.prioridad) {
            return prioridad < otro.prioridad; // Prioridad más alta tiene mayor prioridad en el montículo
        } else {
            return ordenDeLlegada > otro.ordenDeLlegada; // En caso de igual prioridad, el que llegó primero tiene prioridad
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    int E;
    cin >> E; // Lee el número de eventos

    priority_queue<Cuentahabiente> cola; // Montículo para mantener a los cuentahabientes ordenados por prioridad
    vector<string> atendidos; // Vector para almacenar los nombres de los cuentahabientes atendidos

    int ordenDeLlegada = 0; // Variable para llevar la cuenta del orden de llegada de los cuentahabientes

    // Bucle para procesar cada evento
    for (int i = 0; i < E; ++i) {
        char evento;
        cin >> evento; // Lee el tipo de evento

        if (evento == 'C') { // Si llega un cuentahabiente
            string nombre;
            int prioridad;
            cin >> nombre >> prioridad; // Lee el nombre y la prioridad del cuentahabiente
            cola.push(Cuentahabiente(nombre, prioridad, ordenDeLlegada++)); // Agrega el cuentahabiente al montículo con su orden de llegada
        } else if (evento == 'S') { // Si se realiza un sorteo
            char letra;
            int incremento;
            cin >> letra >> incremento; // Lee la letra y el incremento de prioridad
            // Itera sobre todos los cuentahabientes en la cola y les suma el incremento si su nombre empieza con la letra del sorteo
            priority_queue<Cuentahabiente> nuevaCola;
            while (!cola.empty()) {
                Cuentahabiente actual = cola.top();
                cola.pop();
                if (actual.nombre[0] == letra) {
                    actual.prioridad += incremento;
                }
                nuevaCola.push(actual);
            }
            cola = nuevaCola; // Actualiza la cola con los cambios realizados
        } else if (evento == 'A') { // Si se atiende a un cuentahabiente
            if (!cola.empty()) {
                atendidos.push_back(cola.top().nombre); // Añade el nombre del cuentahabiente atendido al vector de atendidos
                cola.pop(); // Remueve al cuentahabiente atendido del montículo
            }
        }
    }

    // Imprime los nombres de los cuentahabientes atendidos en el orden en que fueron atendidos
    for (const string& nombre : atendidos) {
        cout << nombre << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Les agradecería su ayuda, excelente día.

¿Cuál es el problema que estás encontrando?

Mi programa es TLE "Tiempo límite excedido".

Si analizamos un poco el código no es difícil percatarse de que esto:
  priority_queue<Cuentahabiente> nuevaCola;
    while (!cola.empty()) {
        Cuentahabiente actual = cola.top();
        cola.pop();
        if (actual.nombre[0] == letra) {
            actual.prioridad += incremento;
        }
        nuevaCola.push(actual);
    }

está consumiendo un tiempo precioso. Cada vez que hay un sorteo iteras sobre la cola y creas otra nueva solo para alterar la prioridad de algunos de sus items.
En este tipo de ejercicios debes analizar siempre los detalles del enunciado y las suposiciones que puedes hacer. Hay un detalle muy importante:

Durante el sorteo se extrae una letra y un entero I de la tómbola: a
los clientes que estén formados en ese momento y cuyos nombres inicien
con esa letra se les sumarán I puntos a su prioridad

esto implica que tras cada sorteo la posición relativa en la cola para los clientes ganadores no cambia entre si. Estos detalles suelen estar ahí para que te aproveches de ellos, en este caso te permite usar la vieja técnica de "divide y vencerás". Por ejemplo, aún usando colas de prioridad de la STDLib puedes hacer algo como:

Crea una cola para cada inicial.
Cuando se produzca un sorteo no modifique las colas, simplemente almacena el bonus de prioridad ganado para la cola ganadora en algún lado.
Cuando ingrese un nuevo cliente lo insertas en la cola a la que pertenece según la inicial de su nombre, pero corrigiendo su prioridad de acuerdo al bonus actual de la cola.
Cuando tengas que atender a un cliente simplemente obtén el cliente con mayor prioridad de los que están en cabeza de cada una de las colas teniendo en cuenta el bonus de prioridad de cada una.

La ventaja de esto es que los sorteos no implican reordenar ninguna cola que es la operación más costosa en tu implmentación, ahora solo es cuestión de incrementar un entero...
Una implementación tosca de esta idea usando simplemente un array para almacenar las colas podría ser:
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>


struct Cuentahabiente {
    std::string nombre;
    int prioridad;
    uint orden_llegada;
    Cuentahabiente(std::string nombre, int prioridad, uint orden_llegada) : nombre(nombre), prioridad(prioridad), orden_llegada(orden_llegada) {}
    bool operator<(const Cuentahabiente& otro) const {
        if (prioridad == otro.prioridad) {
            return orden_llegada > otro.orden_llegada;
        }
        return prioridad < otro.prioridad;
    }
};


struct Cola {
    int bonus_prioridad = 0;
    std::priority_queue<Cuentahabiente> pq;
    bool operator<(const Cola& otro) const {
        if (pq.empty()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (otro.pq.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        auto cuentahabiente = pq.top();
        auto otro_cuentahabiente = otro.pq.top();
        auto prioridad = cuentahabiente.prioridad + bonus_prioridad;
        auto otro_prioridad = otro_cuentahabiente.prioridad + otro.bonus_prioridad;
        if (prioridad == otro_prioridad) {
            return cuentahabiente.orden_llegada > otro_cuentahabiente.orden_llegada;
        }
        return prioridad < otro_prioridad;
    }
};


int main() {
    int E;
    std::cin >> E;

    Cola colas[27] = { Cola{} };
    uint orden_llegada = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < E; ++i) {
        char evento;
        std::cin >> evento;

        if (evento == 'C') {
            std::string nombre;
            int prioridad;
            std::cin >> nombre >> prioridad;
            auto cola = &colas[nombre[0] - 65];
            cola->pq.push(
                Cuentahabiente(
                    nombre,
                    prioridad - cola->bonus_prioridad,
                    orden_llegada
                )
            );
            orden_llegada += 1;
            
        } else if (evento == 'S') {
            char letra;
            int incremento;
            std::cin >> letra >> incremento;
            auto cola = &colas[letra - 65];
            cola->bonus_prioridad += incremento;

        } else if (evento == 'A') {
            auto cola = std::max_element(std::begin(colas), std::end(colas));
            std::cout << cola->pq.top().nombre << std::endl;
            cola->pq.pop();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

He intentado mantener el código simple y mantener un poco tu idea original, la estructura para los items de las colas es básicamente la que tu usas. Esto debería permitirte pasar el test si no he pasado algo por alto, aunque hay sin duda espacio de mejora creo que muestra una posible forma de atacar el problema.
